# Replacing multiple lines in Unix

Tags: awk, sed

I have following set of XML data. And I want to add **delimiter** when main record ends.

```
  <Record contentId="501" levelId="2"  parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="51873" levelId="361"  parentId="0">
         <Field id="27277" abc="e0f89f0c-6eed-4092-81b2-f8551df81998" type="4">
    </Record>
    <Field id="15584" abc="007ead3c-d1f9-47e2-aaac-c99553fc2a54" type="4">
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="5021427" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="5099659" parentId="0">
      <Field id="27257" abc="b5eab609-5b3d-44b0-b64b-0eee0fe00951" type="6">5099659</Field>
    </Record>
  </Record>
```

I want to change this to

```
  <Record contentId="501" levelId="2"  parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="51873" levelId="361"  parentId="0">
         <Field id="27277" abc="e0f89f0c-6eed-4092-81b2-f8551df81998" type="4">
    </Record>
    <Field id="15584" abc="007ead3c-d1f9-47e2-aaac-c99553fc2a54" type="4">
  </Record>@@@@
  <Record contentId="5021427" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="5099659" parentId="0">
      <Field id="27257" abc="b5eab609-5b3d-44b0-b64b-0eee0fe00951" type="6">5099659</Field>
    </Record>
  </Record>
```

Command I am using sed command as

```
sed '/^<\/Record>$/{$!{ N; s/^<\/Record>\n  <Record/<\/Record>@@@@\n  <Record/;ty;P;D;:y}}'
```

Comment: _Why_ do you want to add that delimiter to the otherwise perfectly parsable XML (apart from lacking root element)? It would break the XML.

Comment: @Kusalananda I am trying to separate these records so I can use it in my ETL code

Comment: ETL strategies should consider parsing XML structures without any custom delimiters. What you are trying to achieve has no real benefits

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have existing code which I dont want to change. Adding a delimiter will solve my problem. Can you help please.

Comment: Doing this will lead to breaking a valid XML structure. This idea should not be implemented, do reconsider non-robust features of your "existing code"

Comment: I am converting this xml into .csv and delimiters are helpful to separate the records. I need this csv in other applications which does not support xml. so this is requirement for me. Can you please help @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @Shriraj, I can help with the following advise: 1) delete this question; 2) post a question with a valid title: "Convert XML structure into CSV record set" and a valid testable xml structure and expected CSV record set.

Comment: +1 to @RomanPerekhrest `xmllint` or `xsltproc` would do fine, I use the former to extract a single value and the latter to extract bunch of data.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest well I already have my code written. Thing is that my file structure is changed now. Previously I was getting single record with <Record> -- Open </Record> closed.  I used to add delimeters using  
>sed '/<\/Record>/c\<\/Record>@@@@'

Now I am getting nested records and thus just need to amend code. 

Csv conversions are already taken care in my ETL codes and I cant change the code now.

Comment: @Shriraj, accept my condolences ... and good luck

Comment: Well Guys I really understand your concerns here. But I am looking for the solution to my existing problem and changing xml structure does not cause any problem for my code or requirements. I am not using this file elsewhere and I do take back up of this file if I wish to use it in future. So can you please help me to fix this. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the following work for you: `sed -e '$ ! s=^</Record>$=</Record>@@@@=' <your_file>`

Comment: How do you define a `main record`? Is it just the first record in the file? If not why does the last record in the file not have `@@@@` after it?

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for all your valuable comments. I could solve my issue using below script.

```
for j in `cat -n test.xml |grep '<Record '|awk '{print $1-1}'`; do for i in `cat -n test.xml |grep '</Record>' |awk '{print $1}'`; do if [ $i -eq $j ]; then sed -i ""$i"s/<\/Record>/<\/Record>@@@@/" test.xml; fi; done; done
```